# Is it bad to leave a laptop screen on with the same image for long periods of time

Tags: display, sleep, teamviewer

I need to leave my laptop on for around 8 hours so I can control it with TeamViewer when needed. It would not be in any kind of sleep mode, like if I sat there moving the mouse around every 3 seconds to keep it on. I do not have to worry about keeping it on though, because a TeamViewer connection prevents it from going to sleep.

If I left my computer on for that long without the picture on the monitor changing would it cause any damage?

Comment: Turn the brightness down and it should be fine. Even set the screen to turn off (but not suspend).

Comment: If you're using a remote connection to interact with the computer why do you think the image won't change? Anyway no, not a problem, but this seems to be a misunderstanding of what Teamviewer does.

Comment: I was just planning on leaving the connection on in the background of the connecting computer and only using it when I need, not doing all my work on the remote system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this (and to put your mind at ease) is to set a screen timeout of 10 minutes. This action does not suspend the machine. When it is not in use, it will go out. I do this with my equipment here.

Answer (score 0):

[Screen burn-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in), also known as image retention, varies depending on screen technology and usage. Briefly, if a screen displays the same image for under 100 hours, the burn-in risk is negligible. However, continuous use, especially 24/7, significantly increases this risk due to LED degradation from heat and power consumption.

LCDs, including IPS and VA panels, are more resistant to burn-in, thanks to their uniform LED backlighting. I presume most laptops except premium ones would fall into this category. OLED screens, in contrast, are more susceptible, with noticeable burn-in potentially occurring after around 1000 hours of use. For detailed information, refer to the Wikipedia article on [Screen Burn-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in) and [Reddit's explanation on OLED burn-in](https://www.reddit.com/r/OLED/comments/ee7tfl/oled_burnin_explained/).